# How to run a FOR LOOP over a csv file

Tags: python

I am trying to run the following code over a CSV file, but the code is showing an error that the input data type should be a str and not an int, but I have checked the data type and it is a float. I have tried every conversion from string, to float, to int, but nothing seems to work. please tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
    print(stdized_data.X.dtypes)
    for element in stdized_data:
        if element != 0:
           log(element + 1)

        else: 
            log(element + 2)

     ###################################OUTPUT################################
     float64

     --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     TypeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
     <ipython-input-163-6e534ce31c6a> in <module>()
     9 for element in stdized_data:
     10     if element != 0:
---> 11         log(str(element) + 1)
     12 
     13     else:

      TypeError: must be str, not int
```

I have loaded the file using pd.read_csv function.

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, not images.

Comment: Using methods as described in [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) might enable you to solve your problem.

Comment: Take a moment to read your title, then read your question. Does the title accurately reflect the question?

Comment: I am unable to run a for loop over the CSV file I have tried several times but none of them worked, that I why I wish to know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is probably this -

```
log(str(element + 1))
```

What you are doing is -

```
log(str(element) + 1)
```

You have converted `element` to `string` but 1 is still an integer and you can't add string and integer

Comment: Can you post `type(element)`?

Comment: I checked the type it return float64

Comment: Try this `((element + 1).astype(str))` @SanskritiBajaj

Comment: I am getting the same error, for your information X is an array of floats.

Comment: And `print(element)`, you get? @SanskritiBajaj

Comment: I have added an image along with the question, it will give you a sense of how the data looks like. It is a file that has a few arrays and each array has values in it. @ThatBird

Comment: Don't add an image of you data, paste it in your question so we could replicate it on our pc @SanskritiBajaj

Comment: I cannot paste images in my question

Comment: You can but we can not copy data from your images. Also can you tell me what happens if you `print(element)` because I think you are looping over rows with `stdized_data` but not on the values in the row

Comment: When I print(element) it returns X

Comment: Yes, I guess I am looping over the rows and not the values.

Comment: So if it returns `X` that means you are looping over the first row as well and since 'X' is a string, you can not add string to integer. Try looping from the 2nd row

Comment: How can I specifically loop from the second row?@ThatBird

Comment: I think you need to study [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)